# Making a custom function to comment out a range of lines

Tags: vimrc, comments, functions

I want to make block commenting easy. To comment out a range of lines, what I can do is something like: `:17,21s/^/#` This will comment lines 17 to 21 in Python. But I don't want to write the whole string search and replacement pattern all the time.

Initially I thought of making a parameterized mapping for this, where I could pass the line numbers as parameters to string search and replacement map but then realised that mappings cannot have parameters.

Then I got this function which will comment a range and the comment character can be passed to it as well (like # in Python and // in JavaScript):

```
command! -range -nargs=? Co call CommentThis(<line1>, <line2>, <q-args>)
function! CommentThis(l1, l2, lead)
    let l:lead = a:lead == '' ? '#' : a:lead
    exe printf('%i,%is+^+%s', a:l1, a:l2, l:lead)
endf
```

Now doing something like `:17,21Co` will achieve the task and I can do `:17,21Co//` (for adding `//` instead of default `#`)

My question is: How can I modify this function so as to make it work as a comment toggle? Or add a different command line to it so that I can use command 'Co' for commenting and 'Cu' to uncomment? A search and replace pattern to uncomment a python comment would be `:17,21s/^#/`.

**PS:**
The reason I don't want to use [NERD Commentor](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/the-nerd-commenter) is that it doesn't support ranges, it just supports count, where I have to either take the cursor to the line I want to comment or select it.
Another plugin I found is [Commentary VIM](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/README.markdown) but its command `:17,21Commentary` is too long for me.

Comment: You can already shorten `:Commentary` to `:Co` like so `:17,21Co`.

Comment: How can I do that @romainl?

Comment: `:17,21call NERDComment('n', 'Toggle')`

Comment: Only If I wanted to type down this big command @SatoKatsura

Comment: Which is why you'd write a `command` for it.  The function does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Please guide how that would be done

Comment: `command! -range Co <line1>,<line2>call NERDComment('n', 'Toggle')`

Comment: By just typing `:17,21Co<CR>`.

Comment: Most of these comments should really be answers...short answers are okay, so let's show the world (and Area 51) how good our "answers ratio" and "time to first answer" really are!  :)

Comment: I would still like some to improve this function to make uncommenting code as well in it

Comment: And nerd commentor has a lot of flaws. It doesn't comment blank lines and what not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now doing something like :17,21Co will achieve the task and I can do :17,21Co// (for adding // instead of default #)

tpope's commentary does this, just tab-expand the command into `:17,21Commentary`. It'll autodetect filetypes so you don't have to worry about passing `#` or `//`. It wont comment blank lines, although I'm not sure why that's necessary?

Comment: What is the feature to uncomment a line then?

Comment: The same command, it acts as a toggle like you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a custom function for commenting in COBOL, you can use something similar for Python.

```
function! Comment(currmode) range
    let origpos=getpos('.')
    if a:currmode=="visual"
       if mode()=="v"
           let [linestart, colstart] = getpos("v")[1:2]
           let [lineend, colend] = getpos(".")[1:2]
       else
           let [linestart, colstart] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
           let [lineend, colend] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
       end
       if (line2byte(linestart)+colstart) > (line2byte(lineend)+colend)
           let [linestart, colstart, lineend, colend] =
           \   [lineend, colend, linestart, colstart]
       end
       let comcount=lineend - linestart + 1
       call setpos('.',[0,linestart,1])
    else
       let comcount=v:count1
       let linestart=line('.')
    endif
    if strpart(getline(linestart),6,1) == '*'
       let comment=0
       let label='uncomment'
    else
       let comment=1
       let label='comment'
    endif
    call inputsave()
    let tag = input('Tag for '.label.': ')
    call inputrestore()
    let tag=strpart(Pad(tag,6),0,6)
    let i=1
    while i <= comcount
       if !comment
          let newline=substitute(getline('.'),'^.......',tag.' ','')
          call setline('.',newline)
       else
          let newline=substitute(getline('.'),'^.......',tag.'*','')
          call setline('.',newline)
       endif
       let i = i+1
       call setpos('.',[0,linestart+i-1,1])
    endwhile
    call setpos('.',origpos)
endfunction
```

And add the following mapping

```
nmap <silent>cp   :<C-U>call Comment('normal')<CR>
vmap <silent>cp   :<C-U>call Comment('visual')<CR>
```

COBOL commenting is very specific - comment is `*` in the 7th column of the line. With this code I can comment code using - a range, visual block, single line and add custom Tag (1st 6 chars of the line) using input at run-time (you probably won't need this).

Ex. If I want to comment 5 lines starting from current line I can-

a. `5cp` in normal mode
   b. select 5 lines using visual block (V-LINE or V-BLOCK) and hit `cp`

Similarly for un-commenting.

The function basically computes the first and last line of the range. For `visual mode` I use `getpos` and for `normal mode` I use `v:count1`. Once I get the range, I run the comment/uncomment code in loop to insert the tag and an * in the 7th column.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it manually until I found [Commentary Master](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/plugin/commentary.vim) which I now used.

I was in the process of writing a function but had got to use some mappings or a macro that I loaded when the `ft` was right

For example I used for something like the following, assuming ft=txt but using a sql format comment

```
  This a a non comment line
 This is  
 So's this  
 This isn't
 This is
```

for example recording a macro in `w` i e`qw` which goes to the beginning of th current line inserts a `/*` then adds to the end of the line an `*/` would look like this `0i/* ^[A */^[` and when you `@w` on each line does this

```
This a a non comment line
/* This is   */
/* So's this   */
This isn't
/* This is   */
```

However for me it was easier to set ft specific registers eg `autocmd FileType txt let @b='<!--'` which a `C-Rb` in insert mode put the `/*` and a matching command mapping to `@e` would put the close comment.

I had a matching command that removed them in one go, which I've deleted. :(

I prefer the plugin now as I didn't have time to write a function properly